# Simplest way to implement AR app displaying provided 3D model

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I have 3D model from [sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/overview-of-the-lymphatic-system-model-3-28be358c57c54e8e9c3292f9a3040f3b) which can be downloaded in `.obj`, `.gItf` or `.usdz`.

What is the easiest way to create a AR app for iOS which will only display the model?
*(so that user can see the details of the model)*

Comment: Hi @Paulina did you solve this issue to load the sketchfab on the iOS. ?

Answer (score 0):

To create the simplest AR app for iOS, you need to write just several lines of code. Open an ARKit/SceneKit template in Xcode, delete all lines in `ViewController.swift` file and paste the following code instead.

```
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        sceneView.scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/model.usdz")!
        sceneView.session.run(ARWorldTrackingConfiguration())
    }
}
```

Do not forget to scale your `.usdz` model. Quite often it's 100 times bigger than necessary. That's because ARKit and SceneKit are measured in meters, although your model may be in centimetres. You can check it in Xcode's Inspector (`bounding box` parameter).